# Spark not using all nodes after resizing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I've got an EMR cluster that I'm trying to use to execute large text processing jobs, and I had it running on a smaller cluster, however after resizing the master keeps running the jobs locally and crashing due to memory issues.

This is the current configuration I have for my cluster:

```
[
    {
        "classification":"capacity-scheduler", 
        "properties":
            {
                "yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator":"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator"
            },
        "configurations":[]
    },
    {
        "classification":"spark",
        "properties":
            {
                "maximizeResourceAllocation":"true"
            },
        "configurations":[]
    },
    {
        "classification":"spark-defaults", 
        "properties":
            {
                "spark.executor.instances":"0",
                "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled":"true"
            },
        "configurations":[]
    }
]
```

This was a potential solution I saw from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940884/why-does-yarn-on-emr-not-allocate-all-nodes-to-running-spark-jobs?rq=1), and it did work before I resized.

Now whenever I attempt to submit a spark job like this `spark-submit mytask.py`
I see tons of log entries where it doesn't seem to leave the master host, like so:

```
 17/08/14 23:49:23 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0,localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 405141 bytes)
```

I've tried different parameters, like setting `--deploy-mode cluster`  and `--master yarn`, since yarn is running on the master node, but still seeing all the work being done by the master host, while the core nodes sit idle.

Is there  another configuration I'm missing, preferably one that doesn't require rebuilding the cluster?

Comment: `spark.executor.instances":"0"` looks like a problem....

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I overwrite that when I do spark-submit --num-executors 2, correct?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt whenever I set that to 2 the cluster fails to start

Comment: Why do you specify it at all? If you specify number of executors in spark-submit, there is no reason to put it in the configs.