# Why doesn't my Spark Yarn client runs on all available worker machines?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, worker, executor

I am running an application on Spark cluster using YARN client mode with 4 nodes. Other then Master node there are three worker nodes available but spark execute the application on only two workers. Workers are selected at random, there aren't any specific workers that get selected each time application is run.

For the worker not being used, the following lines got printed in the logs:

**INFO  Client:54**

```
 client token: N/A
  diagnostics: N/A
  ApplicationMaster host: 192.168.0.67
  ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
  queue: default
  start time: 1550748030360
  final status: UNDEFINED
  tracking URL: http://aiserver:8088/proxy/application_1550744631375_0004/
  user: root
```

The following is the `spark-submit` command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --class com.i2c.chprofiling.App App.jar \
--num-executors 4 --executor-cores 3 --conf "spark.locality.wait.node=0"
```

Why doesn't my Spark YARN client runs on all available worker machines?

Comment: What is question?

Comment: @AjayKharade I guess that would be *why doesn't my Spark Yarn client runs on all available worker machines?* (judging by the title). I proposed an edit accordingly.

Comment: @AjayKharade Thanks for your suggestion. Title has been edited.

Comment: *Please check this thread* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940884/why-does-yarn-on-emr-not-allocate-all-nodes-to-running-spark-jobs