# Very long spark process on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

**Context**
I am processing some data (5 billion rows, ~7 columns) via pyspark on EMR.

The first steps including some joins work as expected, up to and including a `cache()` (memory_disk_ser). Then I filter one column for nulls and do a count() of this big dataframe.

**Problem**

It takes hours to then fail with a 'no connection error' (I do not remember precisely, but I am more interested in the 'why' of it being slow than the final error).

**What I noticed**

Out of my 256 vcores, 1 is always at 100%, the rest is idle. The one at 100% is used by a data node JVM.

**Configuration**

I have 4 r5a.16xlarge instances, each with 4 EBS ssds.

EMR is supposed to take care of its own config, and that is what I see in the spark UI:

- spark.emr.default.executor.memory 18971M
- spark.driver.memory   2048M
- spark.executor.cores  4

I am setting myself:

- spark.network.timeout: 800s
- spark.executor.heartbeatInterval: 60s
- spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: True
- spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled: True
- spark.executor.instances: 0
- spark.default.parallelism: 128
- spark.shuffle.spill.compress: true
- spark.shuffle.compress: true
- spark.rdd.compress: true
- spark.storage.level: MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER
- spark.executor.extraJavaOptions: -X:+seG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -Duser.timezone=GMT
- spark.driver.extraJavaOptions: -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -Duser.timezone=GMT

**Question**

What do I do wrong, or what do I not understand properly? Counting a cached dataframe built in 10 minutes, even when filtering out nulls, should not take hours.

**Some more details**
The data source is on S3, on homogeneous parquet files. But reading those always work fine, because the join succeeds.
During the count(), I see 200 taaks, 195 succeeds within a few seconds, but 5 consistently never complete, all NODE_LOCAL (but some NODE_LOCAL) tasks do complete

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to tell what is going wrong without looking at the resource manager.

But first, make sure that you are not 'measuring' the success on non-action APIs (because `cache` is not an action, neither joins and so on).

My best shot would be at the Spark configurations, I would be using `cluster-mode` with these configurations:

`spark.default.parallelism=510`

`--num-executors=13` (or `spark.executor.instances`)

`spark.executor.cores = spark.driver.cores = 5`

`spark.executor.memory = spark.driver.memory = 36g`

`spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4g`

I think the problem is at this configuration `spark.executor.instances` which you have set to 0.

Otherwise, these settings (from [AWS official guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/)) are almost optimal for your used AWS instance types.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit worried about setting myself memory and cores - isn't EMR supposed to find out by itself, based on the instance type? That was my goal - set up a dynamic cluster, which can be used for different workloads via automagic configuration.

Comment: The reason for spark.executor.instances = 0 stems from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34000524/2473382 , and yes indeed, I am running in cluster-mode.

Comment: from my experience, 'no connection' comes when RAM/HDFS is >90% occupied.